# Is it somehow possible to forbid external instantation of an extension class in Zephir?

Tags: php, class, private, zephir

I have not installed or tinkered with Zephir yet.

Because before I do, I'd like to know whether it is possible to define PHP classes inside a Zephir extension that can only be instantiated by the extension *itself* but not in userland.

Sort of a friend or protected/private class perhaps, or maybe a class defined outside of the extension's namespace, or something similar. Preferably not an anonymous class, though.

---

<sup>*I could have sworn some native PHP extensions have similar classes (not able to be instantiated in userland) as well, but it just so happens I can't find any example right now. Perhaps I have simply imagined this.*</sup>

Comment: No if it's discoverable then it's usable, zephir does not add anything like that

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Thank you. Would you mind putting your comment into an answer, so I can award you some reputation and mark this question as solved? Thanks in advance.